# How to exchange data between java class and android activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am having a android activity class and m also using Java class in asset folder of android project. I want to use data from Java class in android activity program and vice versa. How can I do that?

Comment: you have a java class in asset folder??

Comment: You cannot have your java classes in asset folder of andorid project. Do correct your question if you made any mistake in typing. SO that one can answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I am [...] using java class in asset folder`

If you want to use non Android specific code in your Android project, simply add your Java classes to the `src` folder with the rest of your Android-specific code, and use the added classes as you normally would in any other Java project.